# JavaScript asynchronous Promise Resolve

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fabricjs

I am facing problem is controlling the execution of functions called from a for loop. The Sample code is as below. I am using fabric.js for loading some images.

```
    var xmlObj = '<objects>
    <gptimer onfile="gp_on.png" offfile="gp_off.png" x="9.590044" y="7.682292" onwidth="4.685212" onheight="8.333333" nameon="On Picture" offwidth="4.685212" offheight="8.333333" nameoff="Off Picture" name="GP Timer" channel="-1" fontz="10" font="Arial"></gptimer>
    <twoway onfile="twoway_on.png" offfile="twoway_off.png" x="22.547584" y="8.463542" onwidth="5.636896" onheight="3.906250" nameon="On Picture" offwidth="5.636896" offheight="3.906250" nameoff="Off Picture" device="Device" devicename="Two Way" name="Two Way"></twoway>
    <threeway onfile="twoway_on.png" offfile="twoway_off.png" x="36.456808" y="18.880208" onwidth="5.636896" onheight="3.906250" nameon="On Picture" offwidth="5.636896" offheight="3.906250" nameoff="Off Picture" device="Device" devicename="Three Way" name="Three Way"></threeway>
    <gpoverride onfile="gp_override_on.png" offfile="gp_override_off.png" x="49.853587" y="11.458333" onwidth="4.685212" onheight="5.208333" nameon="On Picture" offwidth="4.685212" offheight="5.208333" nameoff="Off Picture" name="GP Override" channel="-1" fontz="10" font="Arial" duration="30"></gpoverride>
    <slide pointer="slide.png" base="slide_base.png" x="64.641288" y="16.406250" onwidth="4.099561" onheight="4.427083" nameon="On SlidePicture" offwidth="3.367496" offheight="27.213542" nameoff="Off SlidePicture" device="Device" devicename="Slide" name="Slide"></slide>
</objects>'
function processXML()
{
    for (var i=0; i<xmlObj.children.length; i++) 
    {
        parseXMLObjectN(xmlObj.children[i]);

    }
}

function  parseXMLObjectN(xmlObject)
{
    var obj = xmlObject,
    elem = (obj.getAttribute('ONFILE')!=null ? 'images/'+obj.getAttribute('OFFFILE') : 'images/'+obj.getAttribute('base'));
    (
        function(o)
        {
            fabric.util.loadImage(elem, function (img)
                {
                    imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img);
                    imgInstance.set({
                    name: obj.getAttribute("NAME"),
                    rawURL: (obj.getAttribute('ONFILE')!=null ? 'images/'+obj.getAttribute('OFFFILE') : 'images/'+obj.getAttribute('base')),
                    left: getScreenX(obj.getAttribute("X")),
                    top:  getScreenY(obj.getAttribute("Y")),
                    order:'1'
                    });
                    fabricCanvas.add(imgInstance);
                });
                fabric.util.loadImage(elem, function (img)
                {
                    imgInstanceN= new fabric.Image(img);
                    imgInstanceN.set({
                    name: obj.getAttribute("NAME"),
                    rawURL: (obj.getAttribute('ONFILE')!=null ? 'images/'+obj.getAttribute('ONFILE') : 'images/'+obj.getAttribute('pointer')),
                    left: getScreenX(obj.getAttribute("X")),
                    top:  getScreenY(obj.getAttribute("Y")),
                    order:'2'
                    });

                    fabricCanvas.add(imgInstanceN);
                });

                var group = new fabric.Group();
                group.addWithUpdate(imgInstance);
                group.addWithUpdate(imgInstanceN);
                fabricCanvas.add(group);

                fabricCanvas.remove(imgInstance);
                fabricCanvas.remove(imgInstanceN);
        })(obj);
}
```

I need "imgInstance" to be added first, then "imgInstanceN" followed by the grouping to work. I am not able to control the loop and execution of sub functions. Please help by correcting the code.

Comment: What is the point of passing in `obj` as the `o` argument to the IIFE when you keep referring to `obj` and `o` remains unread?

Comment: The issue is not the o and obj, I have to get the sequence right.

Comment: Not clear what your problem is. "I am not able the control the loop  and execution of sub functions" is a vague statement that doesn't help.

Comment: The problem is that the for loop finishes before the parseXMLObjectN is executed one by one for each instance of for iteration. So my objects get overlapped. I need something like promise and then.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code can work with a slight modification, if you do not want to promisify it.

So each children can load at different time, and so it can do base and pointer.

`fabric.util.enlivenObjects`  helps you loading a bunch of objects.

Just prepare a list of objects to load in fabric object form, then enlive them all together and you will have an ordered list of image instances to add to your canvas.

```
var processedElements = new Array(xmlObj.children.length * 2)
var xmlObj = '<objects>.... many children .....</objects>'
function processXML()
{

    for (var i=0; i< xmlObj.children.length; i++) 
    {
        parseXMLObjectN(xmlObj.children[i], i);
    }
    // now at the end of parseXML your processed element is a list of objects that  enlivenObjects can digest.
    fabric.util.enlivenObjects(processedElements, callback);
}

function callback(objects) {
  // objects here are 2 by 2 in order, your xml elements
  for (var i=0; i< objects.length; i+=2) {
    var g = new fabric.Group([objects[i], objects[i + 1]]);
    canvas.add(g);
  }
}

function  parseXMLObjectN(xmlObject, index)
{
    var obj = xmlObject,
    elem = (obj.getAttribute('ONFILE')!=null ? 'images/'+obj.getAttribute('OFFFILE') : 'images/'+obj.getAttribute('base'));
    processedElements[index * 2] = {
       type: 'image',
       src: elem,
       name: obj.getAttribute("NAME"),
       rawURL: (obj.getAttribute('ONFILE')!=null ? 'images/'+obj.getAttribute('OFFFILE') : 'images/'+obj.getAttribute('base')),
       left: getScreenX(obj.getAttribute("X")),
       top:  getScreenY(obj.getAttribute("Y")),
       order:'1'
    }
    processedElements[index * 2 + 1] = {
       type: 'image',
       src: elem,
       name: obj.getAttribute("NAME"),
       rawURL: (obj.getAttribute('ONFILE')!=null ? 'images/'+obj.getAttribute('ONFILE') : 'images/'+obj.getAttribute('pointer')),
       left: getScreenX(obj.getAttribute("X")),
       top:  getScreenY(obj.getAttribute("Y")),
       order:'2'
    }
}
```

You can go even fancier and create directly the group structure with base and pointer.

```
{
  type: 'group',
  objects: [{...base...}, {...pointer...}],
}
```

and then enlive the group ( unsure of position then )

Comment: I'm not going to comment on whether this works, because I know nothing at all about fabric. But in the long run, avoiding promises isn't a viable option. OP is going to have to learn to do this sort of thing with promises sooner or later.

Comment: I agree. But in this case using the already provided tools from fabric is fine. You use Promise library or a native Promise implementation to get out of callback hell. This is another implementation, already existing, that get him out of an async problem. In this case a promisify of the fabric library is an harder job.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it throws syntax error at  imgInstanceN= new fabric.Image(img); Would you be able to look into it.

Comment: do you have fabric available in the page? or just canvas?